# Given a set of vectors and a target vector, find the set of scaling factors that minimizes distance of sum of those vectors from target

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I have a set of $n$ starting vectors $\vec i_n$ and a target vector $\vec t$. I have a set of scaling factors $a_n$ for which I can compute the sum $\vec s$:

$$
\vec s = \sum_{i=1}^n {a_i \vec i_i}
$$

For each set of $a_n$, we can compute the distance to target using:

$$
d = \left| \vec s - \vec t \right|
$$

I want to find the local minima (if any) for $d$, under the following constraints:

1. all starting vector coordinates and target vector coordinates are positive or $0$,
2. all scaling factors must be non-negative real numbers.

Is there a practical numerical method for solving such problems?

Comment: What is the ambient space : $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? $\mathbb{R}^p$ with $p \neq n$ ?  Suppose its is $\mathbb{R}^2$ : either it not possible, or if it is possible, you will find an exact combination (the local minima is zero) in general is your vectirs $i_n$ generate $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

Comment: Apologies, I'm probably using the term _base vectors_ wrongly here. What I meant is that I'm currently working in 4-dimensional space ($p=4$) and there is an arbitrary number of starting vectors ($p \neq n$) which I want to scale and sum to approach $\vec t$ within this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are given a target $\mathrm{y} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and vectors $\mathrm{b}_1, \mathrm{b}_2, \dots, \mathrm{b}_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Let

$$\mathrm{B} := \begin{bmatrix} | & | & & |\\ \mathrm{b}_1 & \mathrm{b}_2 & \ldots & \mathrm{b}_n\\  | & | &  & | \end{bmatrix}$$

We would like to find a vector $\mathrm{x} \in (\mathbb{R}_0^+)^n$ such that $\|\mathrm{B} \mathrm{x} - \mathrm{y}\|_2$ is minimized. This is an inequality-constrained **least-squares** problem. Hence, we have the following (convex) **quadratic program**

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mathrm{B} \mathrm{x} - \mathrm{y}\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{x}\geq 0_n\end{array}$$

which should be easy to solve, as it is convex.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. One more concern is an intuitive notion that there might be more than one optimal solution to the problem, but it clashes with the idea that a quadratic equation only has one global extremum. Given that the starting vectors might be linear combinations of each other, would it not be possible that there be more than one solution to the problem? I might not be understanding the quadratic program method, as I don't have formal mathematical training, so I would appreciate any clarification on that point.

Comment: @KlemenSlavič In the unconstrained case, if $\mathrm{B}$ does not have full column rank, then $\mathrm{B}^T \mathrm{B}$ is not invertible, which means that there are infinitely many minimizers.

Comment: That was what I presumed would be the case. Is there a numerical/stochastic method that would allow me to at least identify some of them?

Comment: Or rather, would adding additional constraints to the scaling factors $x$ help in the minimization? How would one approach that kind of scenario?

Comment: @KlemenSlavič In the unconstrained case, the set of minimizers is the the solution set of the linear system $\mathrm{B} \mathrm{x} = \mathrm{y}$, which is an affine space. Use SVD. I don't see how adding constraints would help.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand what I have said as a remark. And we can be helped in this by having a graphical view of what happens.

An essential thing is that you are working with what is called the **(positive) convex cone** generated by the $v_k$s. A geometrical view of it is the inside of a **prismatic cone whose edges are directed by some of the $v_k$s** (maybe not all, because some of the $v_k$s might be combination of others ; such $v_k$s should be to eliminated right at the beginning...).

Thus,

- either vector $t$ is situated inside this cone and there is an exact solution (i.e., $d=0$) or
- or $t$ is outside this cone. Then the closest $t$ is to be found **either on an edge of the cone or on a face of it**. Finding $t$ can be done, either by using the method proposed by @Rodrigo de Azevedo or by a specific method using the **convex hull** to be hopefully more efficient (if you are working with Matlab, it is the very powerful "convhull" function).

Remarks:

1) The cone might be either "full-rank" (I mean by this expression that the set of $v_k$s is full-rank, i.e., generate $\mathbb{R^4}$) or not.

2) The cone can fill the whole space (for example in $\mathbb{R^4}$ if you take as $v_k$s the four basis vectors and their four opposites) but I imagine you are not in this case.

Comment: Agree, the concern about some vectors being linear combinations of others prevented me from adopting your line of thinking, so I decided to opt for the quadratic program approach suggested by @rodrigo-de-azevedo in the answer. It seems to be a better fit to what I'm looking for (the vectors representing features of a set which I don't want eliminated from the sum) and, since I'll be implementing myself in code, more understandable to me at this point. Thank you!

Comment: I understand in particular your concern about placing a positive weight even on vectors that  are inside the cone. I advise you maybe to think about Voronoi tessellation/Delaunay triangulation in order to attribute optimally the weights.